# Aligning labels in Power BI report

Tags: powerbi

I want to display a Horizontal Stacked Barchart with the labels aligned in a Multi Row card. The report have a Slicer where the user can specify a filter so the number of labels will change.

In the picture below... I want to hide the labels in A and show them in B. My problem is that I can't align the labels correctly in B.

[image: example]